# Qt 5.6.3 source configure.exe is not a valid win32 program On windows XP

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, configure

When trying to create a makefile for Qt 5.6.3 from the source code with the provided configure.exe, it just shows me that the configure.exe is not a valid win32 program on windows XP.

Does anyone know how compile configure.exe with mingw32?

Comment: `https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/supported-platforms.html` says that on WinXP, it only supports deployment, not compiler. For that you meed at least Win7.

Comment: I don't know if I should up vote or down vote this question for targeting Windows XP.  =D